# Updating an array in the controller scope from a partial

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using an isteven-multi-select with a controller (ListController) that is using "$scope.mainCategories" for content that is populated by the "ticked" boolean value.

In the header of the application, I am using a select element to allow the user to select a single category (and then be forwarded to the list page). I am using this select element to toggle the ticked boolean value in $scope.mainCategories.

Both are using the same controller, although references separately through UI-Router (possible issue)

```
   views: {
    'header@index': {
      templateUrl: 'header.html',
      controller: "ListController"
    },
    'container@index': {
      templateUrl: 'search.html',
      controller: 'ListController'
    },
  }
```

then the isteven-multiselect and the select element are in the same partial - the functionality works - when on separate partials the functionality is broken.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RecWR6urjztt8FhRqrsE?p=preview)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Please add more details. What does `ouside function scope` mean in this situation?

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl, I updated the title, content and added plunker.

Comment: What exactly is not working in the plunker?

Comment: Voting to close this as OP is not bothering to explain.

Comment: Apologize @Shomz, I am trying to divide my issue into smaller steps and the plunker part is working... I was unable to see that it was working because I am using the ticked value to populate an isteven-multi-select directive. Should I update this question to include why the multi-select is not updating?

Comment: Apologize @charlietfl

Comment: Ah, you're back, retracted my vote! No problem, please go ahead and update the question with the latest relevant info.

Comment: Really need to do better job up front of giving full/concise problem descriptions rather than expecting the code to speak for itself

Comment: @charlietfl, yes you are very right. I will

Comment: Apologize @Shomz, updating the plunker and it is still working...

Comment: @Shomz, I have updated the question and plunker... Thank you again

Comment: The problem is that those are two different scopes. Try logging `$scope` and you'll see one is id 4 and the other is id 7 (numbers may vary). So basically everything is mirrored, but the main list listens only to one scope.

Comment: I should encompass both partials under the same instance of the controller... Thank you again for being so cool while I bumble around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` might not be what you expect because you can't look for index of object in this line unless you're passing in **the actual object**:

```
var x = $scope.mainCategories.indexOf(item);
```

I assume you're trying to pass in something like:

```
{
  category: "Adventure",
  ticked: false
}
```

and to get the index, it won't work. You need to loop over the array and match the `category`, for example.

Your approach for modifying the outside array is fine, though.

---

See this example to see what I mean:

```js
var people = [
  {name: 'Shomz'},
  {name: 'John'}
];

alert(people.indexOf({ name: 'John'})); // -1: the copy of object not found
alert(people.indexOf(people[1]));       //  1: actual reference found
```

---

### Scope update

To manually update the scope, either wrap the code in a $timeout callback, or use:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: _"I assume"_  I don't. It's more reasonable to assume that `item` is the actual object. Like in `<li ng-repeat="category in mainCategories" ng-click="update(category)">`

Comment: In that case there won't be a question, because it works. Oh, we've got a fully functional plunker link now... not sure what's the question anymore.

Comment: @shomz you are right...it's not item passed in from view

Comment: @charlietfl, actually, I'm now entirely confused, because the plunker works just fine.

Comment: think i confused myself too, was interpreting wrong.

Comment: Haha, yeah... he's not sending an index, but an actual object reference, so `item.ticked = true` should work as well as his clumsy `indexOf` variation that goes a full circle.

Comment: @charlietfl, I am using indexOf because I will need to know which selection of the dropdown was selected... tried to simplify example... I am the only one here who is simplified

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.update = function(item) {
  item.ticked = true; // ?
};

$scope.mainCategories = [{
  category: "Adventure",
  ticked: false
},{category: "Fantasy", 
ticked: false}];
```

Just have your function take the object you want to modify and pass that in from the view.

Comment: Actually, this turned out to work just fine, although it doesn't fix anything, still +1.